# Difference between c:out and print the output using $

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In JSTL there are two ways to print the output -

`<H1><c:out value="${theOutput}" /></H1>`

AND

`<H1>${theOutput}</H1>`

What is the difference? And which one is preferred way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both methods `c:out` and `JSP EL` will display output to the page, however there is one major difference.  The `c:out` tag will automatically escape xml output which can prevent cross site scripting.  Using `JSP EL` (the second option) will not escape the output.

When displaying data which has been inputted by a user use the `c:out` tag instead of `JSP EL` to prevent any malicious data input from displaying on the page.

Comment: please tell how it use for user inputted field.we handle escape character in Back End manually.  How to use it during Path Bind